# sync dumped rtp streams

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, rtp

I need a bit of a guidance. I am writing a bit of an application to parse two streams of RTP data to get the actual video (h264) and audio (PCM alaw), it's not a RTSP client but a rather dump parser (Interleved RTP/RTCP).
 Question is now how to synchronise these both streams?

I know I need to do some calculations between timestamps from packets and NTP from RTCP (I research it currently) but what then how to prepare two tracks to mux them into some container like matroska (using for instance ffmpeg)? Do I have to create some empty frames for audio to lengthen it or stretch somehow I don't have a clue how to approach it.